# How to make scrollable LazyColumn items?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am trying to create a LazyColumn. I want to show all the list but for the first item it will fit all the page if I scroll it up it will show second item and so on. The code I am working on is below :

```
@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun someFunction() {
        val list = listOf(
            "A", "B", "C", "D"
        ) + ((0..100).map { it.toString() })
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            items(items = list, itemContent = { item ->
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = item,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        fontSize = 56.sp)
                }

            })
        }
}
```

[image]

Here I have a list includes A,B,C,D and numbers from 0 to 100. For example I want to show first A if I scroll up then B will come then if I scroll up or down it will show the next or previous item etc. I have been searching to solve this issue I also find something like isScrollUp or down but I   couldn't achieve to implement. If you can give me a sample code or link it will be perfect for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `VerticalPager` which will allow you to do exactly that instead of using a `LazyColumn`.
here is a simple example of how to do it using `VerticalPager`:

```
val list = mutableListOf("a","b","c","d")
    val state = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {list.size})
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

        VerticalPager(state = state) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                .fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = list[it],
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = 56.sp)
            }
        }

    }
```

for more information about `VerticalPager` and `HorizontalPager` check out the [Pager documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you :)

Comment: @YunusEmrahUluçay glad i can help <3

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you try this:

```
@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun someFunction() {
    val list = listOf(
        "A", "B", "C", "D"
    ) + ((0..100).map { it.toString() })

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Calculate the height of a single item
    val itemHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { 200.dp.toPx() }

    LazyColumn(state = lazyListState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        items(items = list, itemContent = { item ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = 56.sp
                )
            }
        })
    }

    LaunchedEffect(lazyListState.isScrollInProgress) {
        if (!lazyListState.isScrollInProgress) {
            val targetIndex = (lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset + itemHeight / 2) / itemHeight
            coroutineScope.launch {
                lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(targetIndex.toInt())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working like what I want. Whereever I scroll it goes to A. Actually what I want is for example first I want to show A on the whole page. A will be on page only. Then when I scroll up I want to show B only on the page.